# Deserializing json tree structure and setting parents

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

This seems like a really basic problem, but I'm struggeling to find an elegant solution. I have a Node class that I'm using to build a tree structure. This is then serialized to JSON using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(..)`. In order to prevent circular references when serializing, I've placed a `JsonIgnore` attribute on the Parent property.

This obviously means that the parent is not being serialized as part of each node in the resulting JSON output.

When I deserialize the same JSON string, I want the Node objects to have the proper Parent assigned so that I can easily traverse the tree upwards. What is the cleanest and simplest way of achieving this?

```
[JsonObject]
public class Node : IEnumerable<Node>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Node Parent { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty("Children")]
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, Node> _children = new Dictionary<Guid, Node>();

    public Node()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public void Add(Node departmentNode)
    {
        if (node.Parent != null)
        {
            node.Parent._children.Remove(node.Id);
        }

        node.Parent = this;
        _children.Add(node.Id, node);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Node> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _children.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of the Parent altogether and use something like `FindParent(node.Id)` when you need to find it.

If this not feasible (it should be though)  and you need to have a parent reference my suggestion would be to go through the tree and set the parent references after you deserialize.

Comment: Yep, that could work. The disadvantage with the FindParent(node.Id) approach is that I always need to use the root department as starting point. Sometimes I might want to pass just a child department as parameter to a method and be able to easily walk the tree upwards. I currently have working versions of both your suggestions and will test them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve it was to ignore the serialization of the **Parent** and implement a public property called **Children** which sets my private **ChildrenDict** collection. When I add the children to the private dictionary, I also set the **Parent** property of each child.

Personally, I don't like to pollute my data classes with JSON-specific attributes, because I like to have a serializer independent clean design.

Said so, the end solution doesn't use **JsonIgnoreAttribute** tags and defines:

- a private parameterless constructor, used by JSON deserializer
- a private **Parent** property (ignored by JSON serializer)
- a public **GetParent()** method (for your own use)
- a public constructor taking **parent** as argument (for your own use)

One could also define a **SetParent()** method, although in my code I didn't need it at all.

This code was tested with NewtonsoftJson serialization & DotNET 4.5.2

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace JsonSerializableNode
{
    public class Node
    {
        private Node() { } // used for deserializing

        public Node(string name, Node parent) // used everywhere else in your code
        {
            Name = name;
            Parent = parent;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        private Node Parent { get; set; }

        public Node GetParent()
        {
            return Parent;
        }

        public Node[] Children
        {
            get
            {
                return ChildrenDict.Values.ToArray();
            }

            set
            {
                ChildrenDict.Clear();
                if (value == null || value.Count <= 0) return;
                foreach (Node child in value)
                    Add(child);
            }
        }

        // One could use a typed OrderedDictionary here, since Json lists guarantee the order of the children:
        private Dictionary<string, Node> ChildrenDict { get; } = new Dictionary<string, Node>();

        public Node Add(Node child)
        {
            ChildrenDict.Add(child.Name, child);
            child.Parent = this;
            return child;
        }

        public Node Get(string name)
        {
            return ChildrenDict[name];
        }

        public bool Remove(string name)
        {
            return ChildrenDict.Remove(name);
        }
    }
}
```